# Core Data: Additional object inserted into Managed Object Context after restarting App

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject

upon loading the Root View Controller a Managed Object called *Target* should be created using the convenience method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if (context == nil) { 
       context = [(MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
    }

    if ([fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects count] < 1) {
       Target *aTarget = (Target *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Target" inManagedObjectContext:context]; 
    }

    NSError *error; 
    if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]) {
       // Update to handle the error appropriately.
       NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }

     if(![context save:&error]){  
       //Handle error.
     } ...
```

If I run the App on my iPhone from Xcode it works all fine. However, if I stop the test run and restart the App on the iPhone a new Managed Object is created even though the condition

```
[fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects count] < 1)
```

does not seem to be satisfied (in the end it is, I just don't know why). Once the App runs on the Phone independent of Xcode I can close and restart it without increasing the number of Managed Objects created. Only the first time after disconnecting it from Xcode.
Remark: The disconnection from Xcode causes the *Segmentation fault: 11* error which also appears when I disconnect another Core Data App from Xcode. So I wouldn't attribute this error to my problem.
Any ideas how to prevent the App from creating this additional object? Would you need more code to figure out the issue? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solely based on the code I can see, I would think that this piece of code will create a new object the first time the code runs each time the app is run.

Try switching your 2nd and 3rd `if` statements so that you're performing the fetch first. I'd give you code but the code formatting is turning out to be a real pain to use from my iPad.

Comment: Thanks for your tip. But in order to fetch objects there must be at least one object in the context. If I swap these two statements that won't be the case.

Comment: Saeppi, You can fetch on any entity whether there are any objects in it or not. You just get a zero count. Andrew

Answer (score 1):

Thuggish Nuggets & adonoho, thanks very much for your help. You guided me in the right direction. I switched the two statements as suggested and added the following condition when retrieving the object from the managed object context:

```
if ([fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects count] > 0) {
  id currObj = [fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:0];  
}
```

Without this condition I got an NSRangeExeption error ([__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array) when switching the two statements.
Following your advice, no new object is created when starting the app anew. Thanks very much!